# What's the value of $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2 i!}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

What's the value of $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2 i!}(= S)$?

I try to calculate the value by the following.

$$\frac{e^x - 1}{x} = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{x^{i-1}}{i!}.$$
Taking the integral gives
$$ \int_{0}^x \frac{e^t-1}{t}dt = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{x^{i}}{i i!}. $$

In the same, we gets the following equation

$$ \int_{s=0}^x \frac{1}{s} \int_{t=0}^s \frac{e^t-1}{t}dt ds= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{x^{i}}{i^2 i!}. $$

So we holds

$$S = \int_{s=0}^1 \frac{1}{s} \int_{t=0}^s \frac{e^t-1}{t}dt ds.$$

Does this last integral have an elementary closed form or other expression?

Comment: I think it would be very hard. Even for the integral of $\frac{e^t-1}{t}$ you get a incomplete gamma function in $s$. But there have been other integrals that I wouldn't have expected to be solved that were solved.

Comment: Exchange order of integration + http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+log(t)(e%5Et-1)%2Ft Or directly: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+(1%2F(n%5E2+n!))

Comment: @A.S. How can you exchange the order of integration when there is another $\frac1s$ in front of the integral?

Comment: @wyt Exactly how it's usually done - by switching order of integration and adjusting the limits. Is that a serious question?

Comment: Elementary closed form ? No. An expression ? Yes.

Comment: @wythagoras the integrand has same sign over the integration domain, one can exchange order of integration by [Tonelli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's interesting to see how to get the “closed form” in terms of hypergeometric function. Recalling the definition of generalized hypergeometric function $$_{q}F_{p}\left(a_{1},\dots,a_{q};b_{1},\dots,b_{p};z\right)=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{\left(a_{1}\right)_{k}\cdots\left(a_{q}\right)_{k}}{\left(b_{1}\right)_{k}\cdots\left(b_{p}\right)_{k}}\frac{z^{k}}{k!}
 $$ where $\left(a_{i}\right)_{k}
 $ is the [Pochhammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html), we note that $\left(2\right)_{k}=\left(k+1\right)!
 $ and $\left(1\right)_{k}=k!$. Hence $$_{3}F_{3}\left(1,1,1;2,2,2;1\right)=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{\left(k!\right)^{3}}{\left(\left(k+1\right)!\right)^{3}}\frac{1}{k!}=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{1}{\left(k+1\right)^{3}}\frac{1}{k!}=\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{k^{2}k!}.$$

Comment: Please tell me how to prove the following? $$\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{1}{\left(k+1\right)^{3}}\frac{1}{k!}=\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{k^{2}k!}.$$

Comment: @Manyama $$\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{1}{\left(k+1\right)^{3}k!}=$$ $$=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{1}{\left(k+1\right)^{2}\left(k+1\right)!}=$$ $$=\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{k^{2}k!}.$$ I used the definition of the factorial and then I considered the series starting from $1$ instead of $0$.

Answer (score 1):

By A.S.'s comment, we gets
$$\int_{s=0}^x \frac{1}{s} \int_{t=0}^s \frac{e^t-1}{t}dt ds = \int_{t=0}^x  \frac{e^t-1}{t}\int_{s=t}^x \frac{1}{s}ds dt = \int_{0}^x  \frac{(e^t-1) (\log{x} - \log{t})}{t}dt.$$

So, we holds
$$S = - \int_{0}^1 \frac{(e^t-1) \log{t}}{t}dt = - \int_{- \infty}^0 (e^{e^u}-1) u du.$$